# Configuring Netsuite for SSO through Okta: If the 'email' attribute is provided and NameId is an email, the two must match

Tags: netsuite, okta

I have set up Netsuite as a single sign on application in Okta, and set up Okta as my identity provider in Netsuite. Everything is functioning to that end. If I create a user in Okta with an email address matching their username and give them access to the Netsuite app they can login to Netsuite just fine.

However, if their email field is different than their username/login, netsuite throws the error:

> If the 'email' attribute is provided ( name@domain.com ) and NameId is an email ( name2@domain.com ), the two must match.

Netsuite's help section on *Completing the SAML Setup Page* reiterates this fact:

> If using both the NameID and the email attributes, the values for these attributes must be identical.

I am adding Netsuite as a new app in Okta for existing users of our internal product. These existing users are already set up with logins in the format of an email address and their email field differing from their login. I am trying to find some way to configure Netsuite proper or the Netsuite application in Okta to circumvent the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - but I'm afraid this is a limitation right now as Okta will always send email out to Netsuite with the pre-integrated connector.

A possible workaround is to build a generic SAML connector via the App Wizard in Okta to only send nameID (https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/Using-the-App-Integration-Wizard#Config_SAMLSettings)